# Provider together with FutureBuilder not working

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to create an api structure using the `provider` method. Not sure why, but I'm getting this error:

> flutter: The following ProviderNotFoundException was thrown building
> ShowData(dirty, state: flutter:
> _ShowDataState#947a8): flutter: Error: Could not find the correct Provider above this
> ShowData flutter: Widget

Seems like the error is with the provider function I have, but not sure what the issue is. here's the code:

```
class CoolDataProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  CoolDataResponse coolDataResponse;
  ApiProvider _provider = ApiProvider();

  Future<CoolDataResponse> fetchCoolData() async {
    try {
      final responseJson = await _provider.get('cool/data');
      print(responseJson);
      return CoolDataResponse.fromJson(responseJson);
    } catch (e) {
      print('erroooooooor');
      return null;
    }
  }
}

class ShowData extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ShowDataState createState() => _ShowDataState();
}

class _ShowDataState extends State<ShowData> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<CoolDataResponse>(
        future: Provider.of<CoolDataProvider>(context, listen: false)
            .fetchAllCoolDatas(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          return Text('data');
        });
  }
}
```

Comment: did you try FutureProvider<T> class? https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/FutureProvider-class.html

Comment: did you make sure you have a `ChangeNotifierProvider<CoolDataProvider>` somewhere in the widget tree above your `ShowData()` widget?

Comment: Based on the error where exactly did you create the provider before calling the ShowData widget